# Neo4j decrease in production database size

Tags: neo4j, compression, storage

I compared my neo4j production database  size.
It was 120 mb on 31-may-2018 and on 27-june-2018 it was 100 mb I am analysising a small decrease in size everyday.
Generally our production size should increase as the system is live and no of users is increasing.

I compared count of every nodes in system.
Count showed expected and desent growth and the application is running fine.

I just wanted to know how neo4j store and compressed data internally to understand the situation.

Apologize for poor English.

Answer (score 0):

There is no compression, and I'msure the different size is due to the rotation on the transaction log (ie `neostore.transaction.db.X` files)

Answer (score 0):

One other explanation for what you're seeing could be because of how Neo4j handles deleted nodes and relationships, specifically with how that relates to space reuse as new nodes and relationships are created after deletes.

As node and relationship data is stored in memory, accessible and addressable by calculations using the graph id, when nodes and relationships are deleted in neo4j, those spaces in memory are marked as cleared and nulled out, but memory is not compacted. Those "holes" in the node and relationship stores are still there, taking up space and unused (like vacant apartments that take up physical space, just lacking tenants). However, Neo4j does keep an id store file which keeps track of the ids of relationships and nodes that have been deleted, and are eligible for reuse when you add nodes and relationships later.

The effect of all this results in an interesting reversal of expectations: as nodes and relationships in the graph get deleted, you may see an *increase* in your database size because 1. The stores for nodes and relationships aren't being compacted or defragmented when deletes occur and 2. Ids are added to the id store file, to keep track of vacancies to be filled in later.

And when you start adding nodes and relationships to the graph, you may see a *decrease* in your database size because 1. The spaces in the node and relationship stores that were marked empty (but present and taking up space in the stores) from previously deleted entries are being reused for these newly added graph elements and 2. Ids from the store file are being removed as we fill in those vacancies, so the id store files decrease in size.

If you reach a point where all ids eligible for reuse have been filled, then once again as nodes and relationships are added you will see an increase in the database size, as we need to grow the node and relationship stores, and as we won't be touching the id stores at all (which should be empty at that point, as there are no ids to reuse).

Comment: Thanks, Well explained.